# Android-MPChartLibrary “No Chart data available” Text size

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I do not see any setter methods for the “No Chart data available” text. How do I make the Text larger / smaller?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [Chart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/charts/Chart.java#L406) class, one can see it's drawn via PAINT_INFO

First, retrieve the paint object, then style it as you want:

```
Paint paint = chart.getPaint(Chart.PAINT_INFO);
paint.setTextSize(yourSize);
```

Answer (score 1):

Textsize,textcolor,text message setting,use below code.

```
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "RockwellStd.otf");
    barChart.setNoDataText("Your message what you want to dispaly");
    Paint p = barChart.getPaint(Chart.PAINT_INFO);
    p.setTextSize(18);
    p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#701112"));
    p.setTypeface(tf);
```